# How to make code to close program after 5 seconds

Tags: vb.net

So here is my code and I just want to close the program after pressing any key and then the program should display the message saying your program will close in 10,9,8,7... until it's 0 and closes.I know it's very simple but I just began my journey with coding and I simply cannot find the solution to this.

```
Dim count as Integer
Console.WriteLine("Please press any key to close the program...")
For count = 10 To 1 Step -1
   Console.WriteLine("Program will close in: " & count)
   Console.ReadKey()
Next
```

Comment: Look into [**System.Timer**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2), exactly what would help you.

Comment: Are you making a console app or a WinForms app?

Comment: Console app and please don't send me code used for C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim count As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("Please press any key to close the program...")
    Console.ReadKey()
    For count = 10 To 1 Step -1
        Console.WriteLine("Program will close in: " & count)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Next
```

This looks like what you are trying to do - but remember there is processing time between those sleeps - so your countdown will not be perfect to the millisecond.  You could also accomplish this with Timers.

Comment: What happens if there should be some other kind of process on the same thread? Sleeping the thread is beating around the bush and is blocking...